# Pandas plotting financial data absolute strange behavior of long and short signal plots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, finance

I am having a really strange issue which I was able to resolve in a quick and dirty way, but I would like to understand the reason behind.

I follwed this tutorial: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/finance-python-trading#backtesting

They give this code:

```
# Import `pyplot` module as `plt`
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Initialize the plot figure
fig = plt.figure()

# Add a subplot and label for y-axis
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111,  ylabel='Price in $')

# Plot the closing price
aapl['Close'].plot(ax=ax1, color='r', lw=2.)

# Plot the short and long moving averages
signals[['short_mavg', 'long_mavg']].plot(ax=ax1, lw=2.)

# Plot the buy signals
ax1.plot(signals.loc[signals.positions == 1.0].index, 
         signals.short_mavg[signals.positions == 1.0],
         '^', markersize=10, color='m')

# Plot the sell signals
ax1.plot(signals.loc[signals.positions == -1.0].index, 
         signals.short_mavg[signals.positions == -1.0],
         'v', markersize=10, color='k')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

to produce this graph:
[Tutorials's plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1Ump.png)

I exactly copied the code and followed the tutorial, just having a little different input data (another stock).

However I get this graph:

[My Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6vtI.png)

Now if I take the code to plot the buy and sell signals and move it up right to the point after ax1 = ...
Everything works out the way it should. I tried to change parameters and also just taking the whole data of the axis and filling the Series with 1, just to get a line. It produced pretty much the same graph.

Does anyone know why this happens and if so how to avoid it?

I assume it has to do with some sort of update to matplotlib, since it works in the datacamp environment.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The Yahoo API that PDR relies on to pull stock data started getting unreliable this year.  There's a lot of discussion about it [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/315).  TL;DR - Quick fix [here](https://github.com/ranaroussi/fix-yahoo-finance).

Comment: Thanks for that great tip, but do you really think that this is causing the problems in plotting? In my opinin that is a data problem, but does not really have to do anything with this plotting of the trade signals, or am I wrong?

Comment: In order to find out, provide a  [mcve]. If you think this is not about the yahoo data, provide a code that can be copied from the question and run to reproduce what you see.

Comment: Thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest still kinda new to SO. I'll post that code as soon as I am able to.